# $(3t+1)y'' - (9t+6)y' + 9y = -3.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given this equation:

$$(3t+1)y'' - (9t+6)y' + 9y = -3.$$

Is this a non-linear equation?

How do I find a solution to the associated homogeneous equation in the form $y(t) = e^{\lambda t}$?

Comment: This is linear equation

Comment: You can try a serie solution...

Answer (score 1):

**Little hint**

Try $y=bt+c$ then $y'=b$ and $y''=0$

$$ (3t+1)y'' - (9t+6)y' + 9y = -3$$
$$  - (9t+6)b + 9(bt+c) = -3$$
We have $-9bt+9bt=0$
$$  -6b + 9c = -3$$
$$  2b -3c = 1$$
$$  b = \frac {1+3c} 2$$
$$y= \frac {(1+3c)} 2 t+c=c(\frac 3 2 t+1)+ \frac t 2$$
You can try to find the other solution knowing this...